# CSS float right/left not aligning properly

Tags: html, css, css-float

Not coded since I was about 16 (I'm now 30) and I'm just beginning right from scratch really.  I used to use Dreamweaver and just edit bits of code but now I want to start getting serious about it.

Anyway I'm just practising with this site: http://scott.ewarena.com/blog

The sticky navigation at the top is the problem. I've got float left & float right on the go, but as you can see they're not lining up.

CSS file is:http://scott.ewarena.com/blog/wp-content/themes/bootstrapstarter/style.css

Can anyone help?

(And if anyone can clean up the absolute MESS I've made of that CSS file, I wouldn't mind lol)

```css
.NavAlignLeft {
  font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;
  font-style: oblique;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
}
.NavAlignLeft:hover {
  font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.NavAlignRight {
  font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;
  font-style: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  float: right;
}
.NavAlignLeft,
.NavAlignRight {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="blog-masthead">
  <div class="NavAlignLeft">
    <a href="/" class="NavAlignLeft">Site Name</a> 
  </div>
  <div id="navContainer">
    <div class="NavAlignRight ">
      <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location'=>'header-menu', 'menu_class' => 'blog-nav list-inline' ) ); ?>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Hi Paulie, unfortunately because my CSS is all over the place I'm not sure which section to copy/paste here, hence providing the external link.  Sorry!

Comment: @ScottDavies Part of the debugging process involves removing parts of your CSS so that you can find the CSS that's relevant. Start with removing obvious things like CSS for elements way later on in the page, or that don't appear in this page, and things like `color`. Eventually you will remove some code that causes the problem and viola.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this after removing some code from my CSS file and then just adding some padding-top: 10px; to the div CSS code.

Thanks anyway!